# Add an image on collection view cell having background colour in iOS

Tags: ios, collections, view

i am working on my application in which I have to add an image to collection view cell on selection. Collection view cell is circular and filled with color, so on selection of cell, image of tick should be on that color.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {        
UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSArray *hexaColor= _advantageModelObj.productDetail.carColorDetails;
    CarColorDetailObject *carColor= [hexaColor objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSString *hexCode=  carColor.carColor.hexCode;                            
cell.layer.masksToBounds=TRUE;       
cell.backgroundColor=[self colorWithHexString:hexCode];       
cell.layer.cornerRadius= (roundf(cell.frame.size.width/2));        

cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"colorselected.png"]];

    return cell;        
}
```

Comment: Show us the code that you have try.

Comment: Also show some screen shot over here to understand your need

Comment: so i have collection view of circles cell, so from api i have filled the color to cell , so now on clicking that cell, an image showing its selected must be added to cell so background color is also visible

Answer (score 0):

1. Make global variable

int                         clickedIndex;

2 in viewDidLoad assign to clickedIndex

```
clickedIndex=-1;
```

3. in collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath

   ```
   clickedIndex=(int)indexPath.row;
   [collectionView reloadData];
   ```

4 add some line in collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath

```
if(clickedIndex==indexPath.row){


UIImageView* imageView=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
[imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, cell.contentView.size.width, cell.contentView.size.height)];
imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@“tickImage”,]];
imageView.alpha=0.5;

[cell.contentView addSubview: imageView];



    }
```